# Integrate Spine with juggernaut

Tags: ruby-on-rails, juggernaut

I am trying to integrate Spine with Juggernaut. First I tried to clone fowa branch (https://github.com/maccman/spine.rails3/tree/fowa) but I am not able to clone that branch so I am doing app myself following by maccman/spine.rails3 instead of Pusher I used Juggernaut. For Juggernaut I followed maccman/Juggernaut (https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut/tree/)

I installed the redis server by

```
sudo apt-get install redis-server
```

Already I installed npm

```
spritle@ubuntu:~$ npm -v
1.0.106
```

For

```
npm install -g juggernaut

npm ERR! Could not create /usr/local/lib/node_modules/___juggernaut.npm
npm ERR! error installing juggernaut@2.1.0 Error: EACCES, Permission denied '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/___juggernaut.npm'
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, Permission denied '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/___juggernaut.npm'
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-21-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "juggernaut"
npm ERR! cwd /home/spritle
npm ERR! node -v v0.5.5-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.106
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/___juggernaut.npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/spritle/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

I am getting this error

So I did

```
npm install juggernaut
For this I am getting 

juggernaut@2.1.0 ./node_modules/juggernaut 
├── redis@0.6.6
├── node-static-maccman@0.5.3
├── optimist@0.2.8 (wordwrap@0.0.2)
└── socket.io@0.8.6
```

After that I did

```
gem install juggernaut
```

For

```
spritle@ubuntu:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server start
```

I am getting

```
Starting redis-server: redis-server.
```

For

```
spritle@ubuntu:~$ juggernaut
```

I am getting

```
juggernaut: command not found
```

So for `http://localhost:8080` 
I am getting

```
Unable to connect error
```

I installed the redis and juggernaut. When i run localhost:8080 I am getting error.
I don't know what i did wrong. Anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

I am an idiot i want to start the juggernaut server at where i was installed. Instead of that i started the setver in other place. Now i can able to connect to juggernaut. I can access http://localhost:8080. Now i started juggernaut at

spritle@ubuntu:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/juggernaut$ juggernaut server.js